# ado.net entity framework "retains" changes despite exiting transaction

Tags: frameworks, ado.net, transactions, entity, rollback

hi guys I have some logic problem in my code (adonet entity framework)

here's the pseudocode

```
i = 0

while i < 5

   using transactionreadcommited

   {

     var getuser = (from a in mydb.users where userid.equals(1) select a).firstordefault

    try {

        getuser.moneyBalance -= 10;

       //error here

       some command here causing expected error so it goes to catch ;


        db.savechanges()
        transaction.complete()

  }catch{

     i = i + 1

  }

 }

end while
```

the problem is,:

I get a new user in new transaction every time it retries in the while loop

User's initial money balance is 100.I minus 10, so it becomes 90

but if some command fails, it will exit the transaction and retry -

in the 2nd loop, User's money becomes initial 90 - 10 = 80. shouldn't it revert back to 100, since I recreate a new transaction, and have not committed the first loop ?